# Python - how do you get broadcast from ip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, ip-address

I'm using python `ipaddr` it's working but if I wanna open a text file where i'm getting an ip address i'm getting an error.

This is What I have:

```
import ipaddr
from itertools import islice

def address1():
    with open('address.txt','r+') as file:
        lines = islice(file, 1, 5)
        for line in lines:
            found_address = line.find('Address')
            if found_address != -1:
                address = line[found_address+len('Address:'):] #address = 192.168.0.9/25
                mask = ipaddr.IPv4Network(address)
                resultado = mask.broadcast
                print resultado
    return resultado

def get_network():
    addr = '192.168.0.9/25'
    mask = ipaddr.IPv4Network(addr)
    resultado_broadcast = mask.broadcast
    print resultado_broadcast
    return resultado_broadcast

#address1() #if I comment out this line and I run the next one works...
get_network() #if I run this one works...
```

My ip address from `address.txt` :

```
Address 192.168.0.9/25
```

the same I used in `get_network()`

So why I'm getting error in `address1()`?

output of `get_network()`

[image]

As you can see works... but if I run `address1()`
[image]

I got this error.

Does anyone know how to make `address1()` work? is it possible?

**thanks...!**

Comment: the ip address / mask isn't what you think they are. Why don't you just print them out in address1?

Comment: print `address` before you use it in `IPv4Network()` to see what you have.

Comment: file returns lines with `\n` at the end so use `address.strip()`

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of your code.  Just post the code itself.